# Microsoft authentication automatically signing in account. Causing "Correlation failed" error when user manually selects account

Tags: c#, security, authentication

We've been leveraging Cookie authentication within our .NET Core 2.2 application & logging users in after verifying their identity via Microsoft external 3rd party provider. Just recently, we've observed an error in this workflow which states:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountHandler:Information: Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed.."

We've narrowed it down to the scenario where if a user is already logged in to their Microsoft account (only one account logged in/active)... and if they then log in to our website they are automatically signed in without having to select their account name or any other interaction. What's more, if the user DOES click on their account name, this fires off another sign in request & I believe is resulting in the "Correlation failed.." error due to the request/response cookies being in conflict.

I am able to reproduce the issue from localhost, though our actual hosting provider is within Azure (App Services).

I've already explored some of the solutions/approaches mentioned within the following Microsoft docs which mention configuration for load balancers and proxy servers (Forwarding Headers)... as well as enforcing HTTPS in ASP.NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

These do not appear to address the root of the issue which I understand to be the automatic sign-on/selection of the user account when the security Challenge is made to the Microsoft provider.

Here is a snippet from our Startup.cs service configuration for the 3rd party authentication config.

```
      // Authentication is added via Cookie
      services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Login");
      services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
      {
        opts.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      })
      .AddCookie(opts =>
      {
        opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        opts.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
        opts.LogoutPath = "/auth/logout";
        opts.ClaimsIssuer = "<ISSUER_HERE>"; // *** redacted for privacy
      })
      .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
      {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:ApplicationId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Password"];
        options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = ctx =>
        {
          // React to the error here. See the notes below.
          ctx.Response.Redirect("/error?FailureMessage=" + UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(ctx.Failure.Message));
          ctx.HandleResponse();
          return Task.FromResult(0);
        };
      });
```

Ideally, the "automatic sign-on" behavior is prevented so the user must select their account from the Microsoft account selection prompt (even if they've previously signed in).

For now, we're redirecting the user to an error page, where we can clear all cookies and have the user re-attempt the login. This poses a problem if they continually select their user account during the login process & both requests are conflicting.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 on this problem. Occurred within the last couple of weeks, after being in production for over an year. This is really causing a headache! 

The issue has nothing to do with loadbalancing or SSL, as I'm able to reprodue it on localhost and in our webfarm aswell. Localhost also has SSL protection.

Comment: We are having the exact same problem here. It started a few days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alrighty then, I got it.

It seems a bit hacky, but hey, it works.

```
 .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
 {
     // Your configuration here

     options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
     {
         context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&prompt=select_account");
         return Task.FromResult(0);
     };   
 })
```

Comment: This certainly does the trick for our use case as well! I agree it seems slightly hacky, but absolutely does the trick in forcing the user to select their account instead of the automatic sign-in. Thanks so much, Nicky! We have an open ticket with Microsoft regarding this issue, if they shed additional light on the scenario I'll include the info here.

Comment: Sounds great! I look forward to their response. Ideally they would just update the library, adding support for defining the prompt setting and last, but not least, fix the correlation thing.

Comment: Why pushing the redirect, instead of just modifying the redirectUri (so then the middleware picks up the new url)? I'm not saying the latter works (actually it doesnt), but I wonder why.